# Authorization environment variable gets replaced when executing request in Paw

Tags: paw-app

I have 3 groups of variables in **Paw.app** for interacting with my API.

I have:

- One called `Global` for target API (Production, Preproduction, Development).
- One for `Authentication` (Either OAuth2 client_credentials auth or OAuth2 password auth).
- One for `Accounts` (used only when using password Authentication)

My problem just declared and I think it didn’t do this earlier today so I don’t get what going wrong…

When executing a request containing an Header `Authorization: {Authorization}` which is a Dynamic variable inside my `Global` environment. The `{Authorization}` gets replaced by a standard `OAuth2` dynamic value.

I made a video to illustrate the problem.

https://youtu.be/izFi9aA8kyg

It seems to happen when I change environment `Authentication` from `Client` to `Password`. (When it needs to request a new token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do to help fix this is to uncheck the box "Automatically get or refresh token" in the OAuth 2 settings. But then you'll need yourself to hit the button "Get Access Token" from your OAuth 2 settings (in your `Global` environment group) to get a new token when you get an invalid authorization response.

*We planned to resolve this and have Paw be smarter and lookup where is the OAuth 2 settings in order to update the token there (instead of replacing the whole header). We should resolve this soon.*

Comment: Ok, I figured out the ´automatical´ thing but it's quite annoying as I need to update token whenever I change environment of auth mode or user. Looking forward for a fix by Paw team soon then. Thanks for the help :)